# Guitar pickup switch LED wiring

Tags: voltage, led, wiring

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwCtQG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ok so I have a guitar circuit here, 2 pickups, each one has a on/off switch. I then run them into a master vol and a master tone. From there I run it into a effects pedal built in that requires 9 volt power. Each of the on/off switches has a 6V LED in it that is separate. I'm trying to figure out What I can do to power the pedal and both LEDs from same source.
here is a link to the switch with the LEDS https://www.adafruit.com/products/915

Comment: Have you drawn a crude block diagram of what your doing? If each effect is its own circuit needing 9 volts, then you need 3 9 volt batteries to have a useful life, or risk drop-outs in the middle of a gig.

Comment: Good try with the schematic. I've redrawn it for you underneath in a cleaner layout. (Use of ground symbol removes the rat's nest.) Sleep time here. If you're happy with my schematic you can delete your one above it.

Comment: Are you trying to have the switch leds turn on and off when pressed, like the pickups? Or would you be happy with the leds always on when the peddle is on, even if the pickup used is disconnected?

Comment: Thanks for the help with the schematic! I'm not use to that program quite yet. Yes, I am trying to having the LEDs turn on when I turn on the switch for each pickup. each on/off switch has a 6V LED with a built in 150 ohm resistor. Is there an efficient way to power the pedal and the two LEDs using the same power source or am I stuck using 3 separate 9Vs?

Comment: I think I could use a DPST switch wired to each on/off to make the LED turn on when the switch does possibly.

Comment: Kite, look at the duplicate, and my answer. You can find these switches in DPDT setups. With led.

Comment: Oh I missed that, thanks those will work perfectly. I just need to figure out how to power all of them now, is there any way to do it from one power source? It says the LEDs are rated from 3-12V so could I use a 15V and put a regulator before the pedal so it only gets 9V?

Comment: Voltage regulator added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

The page gives you this information:

> Connect 3 to 6V to the LED to have it light up nicely, there's a built in resistor! If you want to use this with a higher voltage, say 12V or 24V, simply add a 470 ohm resistor in series with the LED connection to keep the LED current at around 20mA.

For 9 V I would start off with the 470 Ω resistor (to maximise battery life) and decrease the value to half if it's not bright enough for you.

You've got a problem though:

> Switch contacts: 1 NO [normally open], 1 NC [normally closed].

Actually the switches have one changeover contact - they're not even separate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmzue1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Required switch wiring. You need a 2PST (2-pole, single-throw) switch.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Linear voltage regulator.*

A 7809 voltage regulator will do what you need to drop the battery voltage to 9 V. Don't be tempted to leave out the capacitors as these are required to prevent oscillation. 'Input' is from your battery. 'Output' is to your effects unit.

Finally, you should probably figure out some method of bypassing the FX should it fail mid-gig.

Comment: So I can use say a 24V power supply then to each switch and pedal use individual resistors to cut it down accordingly? So say between the 24 and the pedal which needs  9V I use a 750 ohm resistor? and 900 for the switches?

Comment: No. You can't regulate voltage to a varying load using resistors. The voltage will fluctuate with the load. You need to regulate the voltage. Where are you going to get 24 V in a guitar?

Comment: for the switches control to get the LED on when switch is on, I jumped one LED post to the Common post and the power to the Normally open, that way when I have the pickup lead going to the normal open it shorts to the common and the common goes to the pot and connects the LED circuit at same time. Will that work?

Comment: How do I regulate the the voltage? Can I use a 15V battery and wire the LEDs in parallel? I apologize in advance as I 'm still kind of new to this.

Comment: Edit your post to show what you've done. There's a schematic button on the toolbar. You should be able to copy mine and make your changes. Note as you draw it that you don't want current going through your pickup coils and you don't want audio clicks as you switch the LEDs on and off. You question said 9 V, your first comment said 24 V and now you're thinking of 15 V. Pick a number! Explain why you're going more than 9 V.

Comment: Sorry, I see that it's not separate NO and NC contacts. They share a common. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yea, was about to mention that. OP needs a DPDT switch.

Comment: @kite05: You can't mix the audio and DC and you certainly can't ground the LED through your audio pot. Draw your schematic for review.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet to the LEDS I only used the switch for on/off so far. The switches have a LED inside but the are separated.  I have the pickup lead going to normally open, and the common wired to the pot IN, when the switch is engaged it shorts the Normally open to the common. So that works fine.

Comment: I'm drawing out the schematic atm

Comment: Fix the question title too. "Constantly turns off and on" is a contradiction in terms. I think "Electric guitar illuminated pickup select switches" might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

It says in the description (reading between the lines a bit) that the LED needs 20mA to light brightly.

You need to drop 3V to get the 9V supply down to 6V, and using V/I = R, we get 3/0.02 = 150 ohms.  So if you stick a 150 ohm resistor in series with the lamp, it will glow brightly.

If you don't want it too bright, just increase the resistor accordingly.  Perhaps 300 ohms to get 10mA.

Use a separate resistor for each lamp.

Comment: Updated question, title, and schematic. I really appreciate all the help, I learn very  quick so this really helps me out. What can I use to power the pedal and 2 6V LEDs?

Comment: @kite05 The obvious thing would be a 9V battery if you want it to be portable, or an off-the-shelf 9V power supply if you don't.  If you're going for a battery, increase the resistances, to reduce the amount of power just used lighting the LEDs.